# React.js protected route has a refresh problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

i have a problem here with my protected routes in react.js so

i go get the token item in the sessionStorage after that i validade if the token is valid if not returns null

so when i did my protected routes it protects the routes but when i have a valid token in Session Storage if i refresh the page redirects me to the login

MOUNTCOMPONENT

```
state = {};
componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('Token');
        const user = jwtDecode(jwt);
        console.log(user);
        this.setState({ user });
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Routes

```
render() {
        const { user } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className='form'>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/registo' component={registo} />
                        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                        <Route
                            path='/dashboardVet'
                            render={(props) => {
                                if (!user) return <Redirect to='/login' />;
                                return <Dashboard {...props} />;
                            }}
                        />
```

Comment: The first render happens before you're setting the user state, which means your App redirects too early, at a time it doesn't yet know it there's a valid token or not. Set your initial state for `user` so you can distinguish between "not checked yet" and "no token", then only redirect if "no token".

Comment: the render on the routes or the general render?

Comment: The `render()` in your question.

Comment: ok so i should set the user initial state before the componentdidMount and after that i should validate in my if statement right?

Comment: React calls render() first, then it calls componentDidMount(). This causes a call to `this.setState({ user });`, which triggers render() again. You cannot alter the order in which things happen, so you need to use a suitable initial state (`user: null`) then change user, whether a token exists or not. Say no token exists, in this case you could set the user state to `-1` for instance. Now your render() method can distinguish between "not checked yet" and "no token". Only redirect if `user === -1`